# import one module (e.g. numpy) in package modules

Tags: python, import, module, package

Is there a pythonic way to be sure all the submodules in a package have the same imports?

for example, suppose I have directories

```
/mypackage
    __init__.py
    module_a.py
    module_b.py
```

and both module_a and module_b need another package, say `datetime`. that is, I have code like this in the two modules:

`#in module_a
datetime.now()`

and

`#in module_b
datetime.now()`

Where do I put the `import datetime`?

Can/should I put it in `__init__.py`?

Is there any reason not to put it in both `module_a` and `module_b`?

Comment: I don't think there's any reason not to put it in both modules. Imports are cached globally, so it's not a performance hit either.

Comment: You should import the module's you are using in a given module explicitly at the top. You *can* put it in `__init__.py`, but `datetime` will trhow a `NameError` in `module_a` and `module_b` regardless if it isn't imported in them explicitly.